# Are GitHub Labels available on CircleCI?

Tags: circleci

This is a question about CircleCI: **is it possible to access GitHub labels on CircleCI**?

Theoretically, this could be done, for example, environmental variables, similar to what is done with the Github tags, commit hash, etc.

The documentation (https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#built-in-environment-variables) does not mention this, so I imagine it is not available, but I would like to confirm this.

Comment: What do you mean *"available"*? Per the docs you link to they're not set as env vars by Circle, but if you're building e.g. a labelled PR you could maybe make a call to the GitHub API ([`/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:pull_number`](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request)) to get them.

Comment: I meant "available" as already "preconfigured" - as with the environmental variables.
However, I didn't think about the GitHub API, and that may be an interesting approach.

Comment: I don't think CircleCI is integrated with them, no - but using the GitHub API directly is a good idea. Put your auth token in CircleCI secrets, use the lowest level of auth you can, and then call the API using whatever scripting language you like.